# How can one connect Django-Timeline to a Redis Backend?

Tags: django, redis, feed

Currently I am following this GitHub project called Django-Timeline to build an activity feed: https://github.com/tiltshift/django-timeline

My question is how can I connect Django-Timeline to a backend like Redis? I've added 'timeline' to my installed apps section. Do I need to change anything else in my settings.py to connect it or does it automatically connect to Redis?

Mind you, my Django app and Redis are one the same Amazon EC2 machine.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Django for a typical relational database before?  If not, you might want to try that first, because Django does not have support built-in to use Redis, or any other non-relational DB, as a backend.  You can get that support using add-on apps like [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) with a [Redis backend](https://github.com/MirkoRossini/django-redis-engine).

Comment: Currently I'm using Postgresql for my database. But for something like a news feed, do you suggest redis or postgresql? and will django-nonrel allow me to connect django-timeline with Redis?

Comment: Hmm, since I fired off a half-cocked answer, I decided to look into django-timeline a bit more, and I think I have a better understanding of your problem.  It looks to me like the purpose of it is to manage a stream of events not necessarily corresponding to items in your DB.  Looking at the sourcecode, it seems like it assumes you have redis-py installed (https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) with the kw arguments for `redis.Redis()` stored as a dict called REDIS_SETTINGS in your settings.py.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @acjohnson55. I looked at the source code as well before, but I was unsure as to whether it was automatic or if I had to add anything else to my settings.py. I'm going to try and look for the REDIS fields that are suppose to be in settings.py

Comment: I think your best bet will be to figure out what arguments you need to connect to your redis server perhaps just from your local interpreter, and then just make those exact same arguments a kwargs dict and past them into your settings.py.

Comment: could you point in the right direction with an example of how I can go about doing that? I'm not quite too familiar with terms such as kwargs dict :P

Comment: In https://github.com/tiltshift/django-timeline/blob/master/timeline/base.py on line 20, that's where the connection is established, by calling redis.REDIS with keyword arguments dict, which works as explained here:  http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/.  Basically you just make a dict mapping each keyword argument name to the value you want to pass in.   Just add `REDIS_SETTINGS = {'arg': 'value', ...}` to your settings.py.  not having used Redis and EC2, I can't tell you what args you need, but https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py should help

Comment: Thanks for all the help acjohnson55, I really appreciate it!